# IE8 CSS different from IE7 & Firefox

Tags: html, css

I'm applying a css style to a select dropdown and input textboxes.

The style appears to work in IE7 and Firefox but not in IE8.

The css is:

```
input.text, input.file, textarea.textarea, select.select 
{
    font-family:"lucida grande",tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    color:#333;
    margin:0;
    padding:4px;
}

input.text, textarea.textarea, select.select{
    border-top:1px solid #7c7c7c;
    border-left:1px solid #c3c3c3;
    border-right:1px solid #c3c3c3;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
}
```

The style appears to apply fine to textboxed but not selects/

Any ideas about why this is happening in IE8?

```
                                    <label class="desc" >
                                        First name</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="nuFirstname" id="nuFirstname" class="text pop" value="" /></li>
                                <li>
                                    <label class="desc" >
                                        Surname</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="nuSurname" id="nuSurname" class="text pop" value="" /></li>
                                <li>
                                    <label class="desc" >
                                        Colour</label>
                                    <select class="select pop" id="nuDept" name="nuDept">
                                        <option value="-" selected="selected">-</option>
                                        <option value="2">Green</option>
                                        <option value="3">White</option>
                                        <option value="4">Orange</option>

                                    </select></li>
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML code as well?

Comment: Just to make sure I'm not missing something - your SELECT tags have a class='select' right? Ditto textarea and .textarea?

Comment: seems to work fine for me: http://www.jsfiddle.net/gFnzg/

Comment: Sorry tried this again and it doesn't appear to be working the same in IE8. I changed the top border color to red and only appies to text boxes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your select boxes to look the same cross browser, I suggest using a jQuery plugin ([something like this](https://github.com/matrushka/Dropp)) to do so. Unfortunately, you will never have consistent results with select boxes if you try to control them with just CSS. It's just the way of the web... for now.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have look at it,

http://www.evotech.net/blog/2009/03/ie8-css-support/[link text](http://www.evotech.net/blog/2009/03/ie8-css-support/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok seems like someone was having the same problem.

[IE8 and border css property on select menus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880460/ie8-and-border-css-property-on-select-menus)

The solution appears to be putting this line in the header:

What on earth is going on with IE8?

Answer (score 0):

Have a read of this and check to see what 'mode' of IE you're in to see how it's interpreting the code. I don't believe this applies to newer versions of IE (ie >=9ish probably)

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html